# C# to Excel, Row identifier

Tags: c#

I am sending data to Excel via C#. I am using an Excel template so I have certain information that goes to different areas on the sheet. My first group I identify as `int defaultBundle = 10;` so this group will start at row 10. I am using  `string[] descriptionParts = DescriptionSplit.Split('|');` to split a lengthy text description. I have a for loop for this *Split and the start row is identified as `int DefaultDescription = DefaultBundle + 1;`.
Now here is my problem : The next group will have to start 1 row after the split for loop so in theory I would need to apply `int StartBundleRow = DescriptionSplit + 1;` but since `DescriptionSplit` is a string I get the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' .

I know what this error means but I am unsure how to make the corrections. Below is my code down to the Split for loop.

```
        string rowIndent = "     ";  // adds spaces to the beginning of the text
        string DescriptionSplit = frmProposal.ProdDesc.Text;
        string[] descriptionParts = DescriptionSplit.Split('|');
        int DefaultBundle = 10;
        int DefaultDescription = DefaultBundle + 1;
        int StartBundleRow = DescriptionSplit + 1;  ----------"HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS"
        int StartAddOn = StartBundleRow + bundleRows + 5;
        int DefaultBundle2 = StartAddOn + addOnRows + 22;
        int StartBundleRow2 = DefaultBundle2;
        int StartAddOn2 = StartBundleRow2 + bundleRows + 4;

        MyApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        MyApp.Visible = true;
        MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(CyberaPath);
        worksheet = (Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets["Cybera Proposal"];
        ColorConverter cc = new ColorConverter(); // converts hex for color
        //customer info
        worksheet.Cells[3, "E"].Value = txtCustomer.Text;
        worksheet.Cells[4, "E"].Value = txtDate.Text;
        worksheet.Cells[5, "E"].Value = cboTerms.Text;
        worksheet.Cells[6, "E"].Value = txtProposalID.Text;
        //Default row start
        worksheet.Rows[DefaultBundle].Font.Size = 14;
        worksheet.Cells[DefaultBundle].Font.Bold = true;
        worksheet.Rows[DefaultBundle].HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
        worksheet.Cells[DefaultBundle, "C"].Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle((Color)cc.ConvertFromString("#49176D"));
        worksheet.Cells[DefaultBundle, "D"].Value = frmProposal.QtyMaintxt.Text;
        worksheet.Cells[DefaultBundle, "E"].Value = frmProposal.ProdName.Text;
        worksheet.Cells[DefaultBundle, "F"].Value = frmProposal.ListPrice.Text;
        worksheet.Cells[DefaultBundle, "G"].Value = frmProposal.MaxDiscount.Text;
        worksheet.Cells[DefaultBundle, "H"].Value = frmProposal.ProposedPrice.Text;
        for (int i = 0; i < descriptionParts.Length; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Rows[DefaultDescription].Insert();    //applies the description for the default bundle row
            worksheet.Cells[DefaultDescription, "E"].Value = rowIndent + descriptionParts[i].Trim();
        }
```

Comment: Convert it to an integer before adding to it?

Comment: Could you give me the example ?..only because I have tried a few different solutions with no success.

Comment: `int.parse()` my dawg it converts string to int but you need to handle the exceptions too

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use DescriptionSplit since it is a string.

Instead, since you're splitting it up into the descriptionParts array, use the descriptionParts.Length property instead.

Example:

```
string rowIndent = "     ";  // adds spaces to the beginning of the text
string DescriptionSplit = frmProposal.ProdDesc.Text;
string[] descriptionParts = DescriptionSplit.Split('|');
int DefaultBundle = 10;
int DefaultDescription = DefaultBundle + 1;
int StartBundleRow = descriptionParts.Length + 1;  --- change this
int StartAddOn = StartBundleRow + bundleRows + 5;
int DefaultBundle2 = StartAddOn + addOnRows + 22;
int StartBundleRow2 = DefaultBundle2;
int StartAddOn2 = StartBundleRow2 + bundleRows + 4;
```

Comment: Well this does send the information to Excel but it doesn't start 1 row after. More like 8 rows after so I am not sure yet why.

Comment: What does your code after the list listed here look like? Like where are you writing the bundled row?